# What android API to call in order to write "command" to CCCD handle in BLE?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Purpose: Write "commands"(quoted because I haven't figure out the right command, I was told it's 0x0001, 0x0010, 0x01, 0x02, etc ) to CCCD handle on the BLE stack to enable notification/indication (from MCU to Android device)

Problem: Don't know the right API, don't know if there is an API, tried setCharacteristic(), did not work, at all.

What I have: I can discover the right char., I can send data from phone, I can bond (taken care not by me, but by the stack anyway) but I cannot send data FROM MCU to Android.

Help, please?

Answer (score 0):

First use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html#getDescriptor(java.util.UUID) with UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB") as argument to get the CCCD.

Use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattDescriptor.html#setValue(byte[]) to set the value https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattDescriptor.html#ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE. Then call https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#writeDescriptor(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattDescriptor) to send the value to the remote device.

Then you must also call [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#setCharacteristicNotification(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic, boolean)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#setCharacteristicNotification(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic,%20boolean)) in order to make Android's Bluetooth stack forward the notifications to your app.

Comment: Hello Emil, I just learned that setCharactersticNotification() alone does not enable notification? Can you confirm it?

Comment: Hello Emil, I just learned that setCharactersticNotification() alone does not enable notification? Can you confirm it? I'm also asking another question, I hope you don't mind, I'm not giving up on this one. I can't think of one humanly possible reason to have so many functions involved just for this one small step. I get the encryption thing but this?

Comment: The descriptor write is needed in order to tell the remote device to send notifications. setCharactersticNotification only tells the Bluetooth stack that it should forward any received notification to the app.

Comment: Thank you once again Emil. I now know that descriptor write also tells whether the app wants to enable indication, notification, or none.